# Make a bucket writeable, but only from a specific domain (or specific Google accounts)

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've got a Google Cloud Storage bucket which is going to be used to store photographs, and a website to upload the photos from. Uploading is working fine for me from my Google account, but I need to know how to get it so that others can upload too. Basically, one of two scenarios:

1 - since my website is quite secure, it could be so that anyone in that domain can upload, but not outside that domain

2 - the company I work for has loads of Google accounts, and everyone uploading will have a Google account under our company (e.g. my.name@mycompany.co.uk). If we could make it so that only our accounts can upload that would probably be better

Either of those scenarios would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have worked - for those interested, I went to the bucket permissions and set up a new permission, using the Domain entity, for mywebsite.co.uk as a writer. This makes it so that anyone outside this domain, or not signed into Google, can't access, but john.smith@mywebsite.co.uk can.